# Should I use definite or indefinite articles in appositive phrases listing someone’s accomplishments?

Tags: articles, appositives, non-restrictive

Not sure which is correct:

> I interviewed Bob, a writer for Time Magazine, **the** winner of two Pulitzer Prizes, and **the** author of three books.

or

> I interviewed Bob, a writer for Time Magazine, **a** winner of two Pulitzer Prizes, and **an** author of three books.

Multiple people have both won two Pulitzers and written three books, so I think a nonrestrictive indefinite article is correct, but “the” sounds right to my ears.

Comment: 'The' is not available before writer (it could be if one were identifying a particular man named say 'Hamilton Forbes':  'I interviewed Hamilton Forbes, the [one who is a] writer for Time Magazine ...'). I'd certainly choose 'the' for the next two determiner phrases; identification is now sufficient to justify the definite article, and this more strongly connotes prestige.

Answer (score -1):

I propose dropping the prepositions altogether.
"I interviewed Bob, writer for Time Magazine, winner of two Pulitzer Prizes, and author of three books."

If you don't like the first comma acting as a supercomma, change it to semicolon:
"I interviewed Bob; writer for Time Magazine, winner of two Pulitzer Prizes, and author of three books."

Semicolons seem to be going out of fashion.

Comment: "A" and "the" are not prepositions but articles, a subtype of determinative. A colon would be better than a semi-colon after "Bob".

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.